# switch-case running weird in Batch File

Tags: batch-file

I try to make my work easily so I decided to learn and write a Batch file which allow me to directly execute some commands, .exe, or something else. However, while using `switch-case`, the result is out of my expected as it continue execute all the `case statement`. And the line from sample output `ECHO is OFF` where does it come form. Below is my batch file.

```
@echo off
cls

echo ================================
echo    Run
echo ================================
echo 1. Remote Utilities
echo 2. Putty
echo 3. CMD
echo 4. Exit

set /p choice=Selection:
:switch
call :case-%choice% 2>nul || (
    echo Invalid Input
call :errorInput
)


:case-1
echo 
echo =================================
echo    Running RUT
echo =================================
echo Done
pause
goto :case-4

:case-2
echo Hello, here is Putty
pause
call :case-4

:case-3
cmd/k

:errorInput
cls
echo Your input __ "%choice%" is not valid.
call :case-4

:case-4
echo GoodBye
pause
```

And here is sample output

[image: SampleOutput]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather use choice, and let's use goto and not call. `choice` does not allow any other characters to do anything if pressed, only the ones after `/c` is allowed:

```
@echo off
cls

echo ================================
echo    Run
echo ================================
echo 1. Remote Utilities
echo 2. Putty
echo 3. CMD
echo 4. Exit

choice /c 1234 /m "Please choose an option"
goto :case-%errorlevel%
:case-1
echo(
echo =================================
echo    Running RUT
echo =================================
echo Done
pause
goto :case-4

:case-2
echo Hello, here is Putty
pause
goto :case-4

:case-3
start cmd /k

:case-4
echo GoodBye
pause
```

Comment: thank you. simple enough. somehow what does `case-%errorlevel%` means ?

Comment: `choice` works of `errorlevel` in order of the choices. So `choice` 1 in this case, will create `%errorlevel%` of `1` making it go to `case-%errorlevel%` therefore means it will goto `case-1`

Answer (score 1):

`call` (when used with a label) means "run this subroutine and then come back here when it finishes." Because batch scripts run top-down until they run out of code, this means that the very last line is both the end of the subroutine and the end of the script.

When you pick `1`, the script jumps to `:case-1`, `echo`s "Running RUT" (plus displays `echo is OFF` because of that one `echo` that has nothing after it), jumps to `:case-4`, pauses, and then runs out of code to run. At this point, the script considers the subroutine call to be over, so it jumps back to the initial line where you called `:case-1`.

Unfortunately, you didn't tell the script to stop running, so it continues on its merry way down the code, once again moving into `:case-1`, `echo`-ing "Running RUT", jumping to `:case-4`, pausing, and running out of code a second time. This time, because you aren't in a call and the script is actually out of code to run, the script finally ends.

To avoid the script from running twice, add a `exit /b` to after the switch statement to end the code. (Also, I'm going to add a `(` to that one `echo` that isn't doing anything so that you display a blank line like you meant to.)

```
@echo off
cls

echo ================================
echo    Run
echo ================================
echo 1. Remote Utilities
echo 2. Putty
echo 3. CMD
echo 4. Exit

set /p choice=Selection:
:switch
call :case-%choice% 2>nul || (
    echo Invalid Input
call :errorInput
)
exit /b


:case-1
echo(
echo =================================
echo    Running RUT
echo =================================
echo Done
pause
goto :case-4

:case-2
echo Hello, here is Putty
pause
call :case-4

:case-3
cmd/k

:errorInput
cls
echo Your input __ "%choice%" is not valid.
call :case-4

:case-4
echo GoodBye
pause
```